# Limit of Multi-Variable Functions

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I try taking the limit along $ y = 0 $ and get $ 4x\sin \frac{1}{x} $ but when I try substituting the value x=0 and/or solving the limit along $ x=0 $, the function is undefined so I'm confused how to approach this. I'm assuming the function is also not continuous at $ (0,0) $ since the first piece wise is undefined for $ x=0 $ and that function differs from $ e^{-5y^3} $. I'm just not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

The limit along $x=0$ is $1$ whereas $|f(x,y)| \leq  4|x|e^{2} (\to 0)$  whenever $\|x|$ and $|y|$ are sufficiently small so the limit does not exist and $f$ is not continuous.

More explicitly consider $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(0,\frac 1 n)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(\frac 1 n,0)$. The first limit obviously $1$. For the second limit use the fact that $|sin(\frac 1 x)|\leq 1$. You can see that the limit is $0$.

Comment: How did you conclude this?

Comment: @krauser126 See my edited answer.